# Django cache_page get last refresh time

Tags: django, caching

I am using `@cache_page` on a view like this:

```
@cache_page(60 * 60 * 24)
def my_view(request):
    # my code
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

I would like to show in the template the last time the view has been refreshed (basically the last time the view was loaded without cache), how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#now) template tag in your template. For example:

```
Last refreshed at {% now "DATETIME_FORMAT" %}
```